# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_sparse'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`sdf = df.to_sparse()` has been deprecated. What's the updated version of this?

Answer (score 0):

`SparseSeries` and `SparseDataFrame` were removed in 1.0.0 (see the [release notes](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ad190575aa75962d2d0eade2de81a5fe5a2e285b/doc/source/whatsnew/v1.0.0.rst#removal-of-prior-version-deprecationschanges)). As you can see in the [migration guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#sparse-migration) there is no performance boost compared to a regular `DataFrame` or `Series`.